# Visual Studio Connects to TFS using 8080 no matter what I do

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017

No matter what I do Visual Studio 2017 maintains an HTTP connection to TFS. Our TFS server was recently moved to an SSL/HTTPS connection. If I disconnect my connection and reconnect to:

https://tfs.myorg.com:443/tfs

The connection becomes:

http://tfs.myorg.com:8080/tfs

NO MATTER WHAT I DO, NOTHING CHANGES THIS URL. I even tried using the IP address of the server. It still shows up as 8080.

**Further Information:**

I discovered that both URL's are still active until every developer is migrated over to SSL. I apparently cannot migrate until the HTTP connection is removed maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the setting in IIS, select the **TFS** under **Sites**, then **Application Settings**, setting name **sslOnly** . If the value is false changed to ture.

Now your team can only access the TFS portal from inside and outside using https only.  This means that VS can also connect to TFS via https only.

More details please take a look at [this link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/222231/unable-to-access-tfs-after-switching-from-https-to.html) which  describing the redirect behavior from the URL.

If above still not work, try to [*clear TFS and VS cache*](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/) and test again.

Comment: My problem wasn't TFS. It was Visual Studio. My issue was resolved when they took down the 8080 connection forcing Visual Studio to listen to what I was telling it and connect to the 443 TFS URL. I wasted so much time being unable to reliably connect that I was considering uninstalling and reinstalling Visual Studio. Clearing the VS cache might have solved my problem and I thank you for your answer.